# Safari iOS debug URLs not showing up, inspector shows "null"

Tags: ios, safari, developer-tools

I have been using iOS simulator debugging using Safari reliably, but today am on a different computer and noticed something strange. I launch the simulator as usual, enable the developer tools in Safari, and go to inspect. But here is what I see, instead of the URL that is being viewed in the simulator.

[image]

If I click on one of those long strings, I do not see the inspector for the URL that I am viewing in the iOS simulator. Instead, I see:

[image]

Anybody ever seen something like this, before?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue, but just solved it by changing the privacy settings in Safari.

In **Safari->Preferences->Privacy** change `Cookies and website data` to `Always allow`.

Hope this helps someone!